# How can I extract images and labels from root folder in pytorch having file structure root/group/label/.jpg for traning and testing

Tags: image, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network, classification

Here dog, eagle, and peacock are class labels for the .png file

- root/animal/dog/xxx.png
- root/animal/dog/xxy.png
- root/animal/dog/xxz.png
  .
  .
  .
- root/bird/eagle/123.png
- root/bird/eagle/nsdf3.png
- root/bird/peacock/asd932_.png
- root/bird/peacock/asd932_.png

I have tried using torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder but it takes animal and bird as class label but i want dog, eagle and peacock as class label.
How can I get train and test dataset from same root folder